# Spring Integration Java DSL - execute multiple service activators async?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-integration, dsl

There's a Job which has a list of tasks. 
Each task has id, name, status.

I've created service activators for each tasks, as follows:

```
@ServiceActivator
public Message<Task> execute(Message<Task> message){
    //do stuff
}
```

I've created a gateway for Job
and in the Integration flow, starting from the gateway:

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow startJob() {
        return f -> f
                .handle("jobService", "execute")
                .channel("TaskRoutingChannel");
    }

@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow startJobTask() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("TaskRoutingChannel")
                .handle("jobService", "executeTasks")
                .route("headers['Destination-Channel']")
                .get();
    }

@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow TaskFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("testTaskChannel")
                .handle("aTaskService", "execute")
                .channel("TaskRoutingChannel")
                .get();
    }

@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow TaskFlow2() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("test2TaskChannel")
                .handle("bTaskService", "execute")
                .channel("TaskRoutingChannel")
                .get();
    }
```

I've got the tasks to execute sequentially, using routers as above.

However, I need to start the job, execute all of it's tasks in parallel. 
I couldn't figure out how to get that going.. I tried using `@Async` on the service activator methods and making it return `void`. but in that case, how do i chain it back to the routing channel and make it start next task?
Please help. Thanks.

**EDIT**:

I used the RecepientListRouter along with ExecutorChannel to get the parallel execution:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow startJobTask() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("TaskRoutingChannel")
            .handle("jobService", "executeTasks")
            .routeToRecipients(r -> r
                .recipient("testTaskChannel")
                .recipient("test2TaskChannel"))
            .get();
}

@Bean ExecutorChannel testTaskChannel(){
    return new ExecutorChannel(this.getAsyncExecutor());
}

@Bean ExecutorChannel test2TaskChannel(){
    return new ExecutorChannel(this.getAsyncExecutor());
}
@Bean
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

Now, 3 questions:
1) If this is a good approach, how do i send specific parts of the payload to each recipient channel. Assume the payload is a List<>, and i want to send each list item to each channel.
2) How do I dynamically set the recipient channel? say from header? or a list?
3) Is this really a good approach? Is there a preferred way to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TaskRoutingChannel` must be an instance of `ExecutorChannel`. For example:

```
return f -> f
            .handle("jobService", "execute")
            .channel(c -> c.executor("TaskRoutingChannel", threadPoolTaskExecutor()));
```

Otherwise, yes: everything is invoked with the single `Thread` and it isn't good for your task.

**UPDATE**

Let me try to answer to your questions one by one, although it sounds like each of them must as separate SO one :-).

1. If you really need to send the same message to several services, you can use `routeToRecipients`, or can back to the `publishSubscribe`. Or even can do dynamic routing based on the `header`, for example.
2. To send the part of message to each channel there is just enough place `.split()` before your `.routeToRecipients()`
3. To answer to your last question I need to know the business requirements for the task.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I didn't specify in question that I would like the individual tasks to execute asynchronously.. testTaskChannel and test2TaskChannel.. Would that mean I have to make these two channels ExecutorChannel

Comment: Also, Please check this thread as well? - http://stackoverflow.com/q/31959480/1866983

Comment: Yes, you can make them as `ExecutorChannel`