# Spring Integration Java DSL - Set RecepientListRouter recipients dynamically?

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-integration, router, dsl

I have a method which needs to execute multiple tasks async'ly.. I've managed to achieve that using the following IntegrationFlow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow startJobTask() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("TaskRoutingChannel")
            .handle("jobService", "executeTasks")
            .routeToRecipients(r -> r
                .recipient("testTaskChannel")
                .recipient("test2TaskChannel"))
            .get();
}

@Bean ExecutorChannel testTaskChannel(){
    return new ExecutorChannel(this.getAsyncExecutor());
}

@Bean ExecutorChannel test2TaskChannel(){
    return new ExecutorChannel(this.getAsyncExecutor());
}

@Bean
public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    return executor;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow testTaskFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("testTaskChannel")
            .handle("testTaskService", "executeAsync")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow test2TaskFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("test2TaskChannel")
            .handle("test2TaskService", "executeAsync")
            .get();
}
```

The above flow is basically as follows:

`TaskRoutingChannel` calls a serviceActivator method `executeTasks`

`executeTasks` returns something like `Message<List<myTask>>`

this `Message` is routed to channels `testTaskChannel` and `test2TaskChannel`
which calls their own async serviceActivator methods.

Now, the issue is that I ***don't want to hardcode the recipient channels***. 
I could avoid hardcoding with normal router by setting the destination channel as a header. However, ***recepientListRouters don't seem to have the capability to get recipient channel name using expressions.***

Is there any way to set the recipient channels dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for delay first of all.

Actually the regular `.route()` can do that for you, because it has exactly has this option:

```
protected abstract Collection<MessageChannel> determineTargetChannels(Message<?> message);
```

So, if your header extraction returns the list of channels, the `HeaderValueRouter` will be able to the message to all of them.

Comment: Wow! that's a really neat trick. Wasn't aware of this. Cheers!